# Saving changes to workbook using openpyxl

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

An excel sheet export from an app adds blank columns and rows to the output data. I'm trying to remove it before massaging the data.

So I have some simple code to delete the first 3 rows and first 2 columsn, then save the changes.

When I use Workbook.save(path) I get a traceback error. I researched on stackoverflow and it looks like this simple code should be working. I've even tried just putting the filename but that also giving similar error.

I'm not sure why I'm getting this error.

**Update:** I corrected the typo Workbook.save(path) to workbook.save(path).

```
import openpyxl
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import Workbook

# Give the location of the file
path = 'C:\\Users\\cbout\\Desktop\\2022 Data.xlsx'
filename = '2022 Data.xlsx'

DF = pd.read_excel(path, sheet_name=1)

# # To open the workbook
# # workbook object is created
workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(path)

# # Get workbook active sheet objectmfrom the active attribute
worksheet = workbook.active

#Delete first 2 columns.
worksheet.delete_cols(0,2)
#Delete first 3 rows.
worksheet.delete_rows(0,4)

workbook.save(path)
```

#### New Traceback Error after updates

```
PS C:\Users\cbout\Documents\GitHub> & "C:/Program Files/Python310/python.exe" c:/Users/cbout/Documents/GitHub/Python/Stewardship.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\cbout\Documents\GitHub\Python\Stewardship.py", line 9, in <module>
    stewardDF = pd.read_excel(path, sheet_name=1)
  File "C:\Users\cbout\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 311, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\cbout\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 457, in read_excel
    io = ExcelFile(io, storage_options=storage_options, engine=engine)
  File "C:\Users\cbout\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 1385, in __init__
    engine = config.get_option(f"io.excel.{ext}.reader", silent=True)
  File "C:\Users\cbout\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pandas\_config\config.py", line 256, in __call__
    return self.__func__(*args, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\cbout\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pandas\_config\config.py", line 128, in _get_option
    key = _get_single_key(pat, silent)
  File "C:\Users\cbout\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pandas\_config\config.py", line 114, in _get_single_key
    raise OptionError(f"No such keys(s): {repr(pat)}")
pandas._config.config.OptionError: No such keys(s): 'io.excel.zip.reader'
```

Comment: try `Workbook.save(filename=path)`

Comment: Also, the `Workbook.save()` appears to have a capital `W`, That should be `w` as you used that as the name in `load_workbook()`

Comment: This is a simple typo: `Workbook.save()` calls the method on the workbook class and not the workbook instance you've created.

Comment: I corrected the typo; however I am getting a new traceback error. I updated the main thread with all that information.